# Run each unit test in a new window

Tags: unit-testing, testing, phantomjs, automated-tests, karma-runner

I am using [mocha](/questions/tagged/mocha) to define unit tests. I want each test to run in a new browser window. Using [karmajs](/questions/tagged/karmajs) all tests runs in one page, collapsing [css](/questions/tagged/css) and `window`.

The reason for needing to run each test in a new window is because the subject of testing is polluting the `window` object.

I know that this will affect test running time. However, thats the price I am willing to take.

Comment: As much as I like Karma, without this feature it is not usable. I am going back to using jsdom with Mocha https://medium.com/podio-engineering-blog/from-karma-to-mocha-with-a-taste-of-jsdom-c9c703a06b21#.p72x6ie0e

Comment: Do you have each independent test in separate file ?

Comment: No, they are in the same file. Therefore, for this to work it would require a tight integration between Karma and whatever testing framework (Mocha). Example if Mocha had an ability to execute `N`th test and give a count of the total number of tests, then the test runner was able to create a new window for each test.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/439) for Test sharding / parallelization that seems to be along these lines, but it is not implemented now, nor does there seem to be a solid proof of concept.

Also their team's current stance seems to be to [not support polluting global state](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/412#issuecomment-20463118) in the way you're proposing.

If you want this feature soon, you'd probably have to create it and submit a pull request.